# getAttribute() returns null for drop down list in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, drop-down-menu

I am trying to pass value from database to drop down menu using getAttribute(). However, it returns null.

This is my jsp (updateLecturer.jsp) file:

```
<form action="updateLecturer" class="sky-form">
<header>Update Lecturer Information</header>
<center>
<fieldset>

<section>
<label class="select">
<select name="selectLecturer" id="lecturerFullname">
<option value="0" selected disabled>Lecturers Name</option>        
**<option name="lecturerFullname"><%=((LecturerBean)request.getAttribute("LecturerFullname"))%></option>** 
</select>

</label>
</section>

</center>
<footer>
<center><button type="submit" class="button">Update</button></center>
</footer>
</form>
```

This is my servlet UpdateLecturerServlet.java) :

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

                    String lecturerFullname = request.getParameter("LecturerFullame"); 
                    LecturerBean lecturer = new LecturerBean(); 
                    lecturer.setLecturerFullname(lecturerFullname); 

                    request.setAttribute("LecturerFullname",lecturerFullname); 

                    RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/updateLecturer.jsp"); 
                    view.forward(request,response);


    }
```

This is my UpdateLecturerDAO :

```
static Connection currentCon = null;
static ResultSet rs = null;

public static LecturerBean selectlecturer(LecturerBean Lbean) {

    // preparing some objects for connection
    System.out.println("JIJIJI");
    Statement stmt = null;
    String lecturerFullname = Lbean.getLecturerFullname();



System.out.println("j444444");


String searchQuery = "select lecturerfullname from lecturer";

System.out.println("Your lecturer is " + lecturerFullname);
System.out.println("Query: " + searchQuery);

try {
    // connect to DB
    currentCon = JavaConnectionDB.getConnection();
    stmt = currentCon.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(searchQuery);
   // boolean more = rs.next();

    while(rs.next())
    {
    LecturerBean lecturer = new LecturerBean();
                lecturer.setLecturerFullname(rs.getString("LecturerFullname"));
                lecturer.add(lecturer);
    }


}

catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Select failed: An Exception has occurred! " + ex);
}
```

PLEASEEEE HELP :( thank you very much[image: Thats the result i got :(]

Comment: What you want to display here. Does it list of lecturers full names?

Comment: If you want to display list of full names then use `List`.

Comment: And also you should avoid writing java code in jsp.

Comment: `request.getAttribute("lecturerFullname",lecturer)` It won't works. error..

Comment: Yes, list lecturers full name. im actually trying to avoid java code in JSP but i couldnt find the solution. Everything i googled, wrote their codes in jsp. this code was a mistake. i commented it but i didnt delete it request.getAttribute("lecturerFullname",lecturer)  .

Comment: You should change the code in `while(rs.next)`. Use `List`.. iterate that list in your jsp.

Comment: i change code in while(rs.next) from LecturerBean lecturer = new LecturerBean();
                lecturer.setLecturerFullname(rs.getString("LecturerFullname"));
                lecturer.add(lecturer); to rs.getString("LecturerFullname"); only. The result still NULL. Sorry i dont understand what do you mean by List . List in html?

Comment: You are having `LecturerBean` as parameter of `selectlecturer(LecturerBean ()`. whats the use of this. I think is of no use here..

Comment: The List in `java`..

Comment: i thought lecturerBean is where it will get the value??? will check about list in java

Comment: for what purpose you are reading value from `String lecturerFullname = Lbean.getLecturerFullname();` .. Is of no use.

Comment: hmmm im declaring new name for the variable from LecturerBean. Where the setters and getters located.

Comment: but somehow its no use hehehe. i just use it to track my programming flow in S.O.P

Comment: Some code in `UpdateLecturerServlet.java` is of no use. Ex `request.getParameter("LecturerFullame");`

Comment: i got error when comment the code

Comment: errors on here  `lecturer.setLecturerFullname(lecturerFullname); 

                    request.setAttribute("LecturerFullname",lecturerFullname);`

Comment: `lecturerFullname` is not declared.

Comment: Since you are using `lecturerFullname` further.. But  there is no use..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103165/discussion-between-mong2203-and-satya).

Comment: When you are calling `UpdateLecturerServlet`. In that case are you passing any parameters to this Servlet?

Comment: yes sir. should be passed to this servlet from DAO

Comment: I'm asking about are you passing any value to this servlet while calling this servlet?

Comment: no. im thinking its will only receive the value to pass to jsp.....

Comment: Does this `selectlecturer()` method exists in some other class?

Comment: no just in that one class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set some attribute in request like this

```
request.setAttribute("key",obj);
```

You can get it display in jsp by a scriplet like this

```
<%=request.getAttribute("key")%>
```

In your case please check the following points

1. Check whether the following code is giving you a null.

   `String lecturerFullname = request.getParameter("LecturerFullame");` 
   If this gives you null then check whether your passing parameter **LecturerFullame** in url.
2. In the jsp please cast the following to correct object

   `<option name="lecturerFullname"><%=((String)request.getAttribute("LecturerFullname"))%></option>`

And let me know.

Comment: i guess my setAttribute and getAttribute code to display are correct. Am i right? and i did your second points to change to String, but still null. However i dont know how to check if getParameter returns null. eventhough ive correct the spell lol

Comment: You can put a `System.out.println(lecturerFullname);` or a log in the method `public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`. Please let me know the output.

Comment: Just set the following code after this code `String lecturerFullname = request.getParameter("LecturerFullame");  lecturerFullname = "Mr Lecturer"` and check no need for logs . If "Mr Lecturer" comes in your page then your `getParameter()` as some problem.

Comment: Now try the above code, then you can confirm your getParameter as a problem. Please give thumbs if you like my solution

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with any of this type of code before, so I'm not sure how the attribute system works, but I noticed an anomaly in your code:

Where you are setting:
`request.setAttribute("LecturerFullname",lecturerFullname);`

Where you are getting: 
`lecturer.setLecturerFullname(request.getAttribute("lecturerFullname",lecturer));`

Notice it yet? Where you are setting it, you put a capital "L" and I believe it's case sensitive. Doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: just noticed, the codes werent supposed to be there. So it does not change anything. Sorry. It  still didnt work. Thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

In `UpdateLecturerServlet.java`.

```
 //calling selectlecturer() to retrieve list full names and store it in session
 request.setAttribute("LecturerFullname",selectlecturer()); 

 RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/updateLecturer.jsp"); 
 view.forward(request,response);
```

Now `selectlecturer()` method.

```
public static List<LecturerBean> selectlecturer() {

//DB query to retrieve all lecturer fullnames

List<LecturerBean> lecturers = new ArrayList<LecturerBean>();

while(rs.next())
{
    LecturerBean lecturer = new LecturerBean();
    lecturer.setLecturerFullname(rs.getString("LecturerFullname"));
    lecturers.add(lecturer);
}

return lecturers;//return the list lecturer fullnames
}
```

In `updateLecturer.jsp`.

```
<%
    java.util.List<LecturerBean> lists = (java.util.List<LecturerBean>)request.getAttribute("LecturerFullname"));
    for(LecturerBean bean:lists)
    {
%>
<option name="lecturerFullname"><%=bean.getLecturerFullname()%></option>
<%
    }
%>
```

[But you should avoid Java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Just for the reference here I'm giving this code.

Comment: hmmmm sorry that im not good at this but in jsp, it says the object cannot converted into list

Comment: **Edit:**  `java.util.List<LecturerBean> lists = (java.util.List<LecturerBean>)request.getAttribute("LecturerFullname"));`.

Comment: No will not come. May be you are missing something.

Comment: i tried to change `request` to `session` still not working out. and I am not familiar with `list` honestly.